# Compare prompt answer with options on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to return either true or false. and want to make sure to accept an answer if uppercase was used.

```
var isSuit = function () {
var standardSuites = ['hearts', 'clubs', 'spades', 'diamonds'];
var question = prompt('which card do you have?');
var answer = question.toUpperCase();

for (var i = 0; i < standardSuites.length; i++){
if (answer === standardSuites[i]) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
   }
  }
};
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gecapehopi/edit?js,console)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: as of now, if someone type clubs for instance on the prompt, I get false, and I wanted to get it to print true, since clubs is part of standardSuites.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the answer string that the user entered to upper case

```
var answer = question.toUpperCase();
```

but compare it against predefined lower case suits:

```
var standardSuites = ['hearts', 'clubs', 'spades', 'diamonds'];
```

That will of course never yield a hit. Try this instead:

```
var answer = question.toLowerCase();
```